# Post request using multipart/form-data for uploading file not working in python but working fine in cURL

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-cloud-storage, shopify

I am trying to create bulkOperationRunMutation for updating shopify products
[https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/bulk-operations/imports#generate-the-uploaded-url-and-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com)

for this, I am trying to upload the data to the google storage bucket, so that shopify and fetch the data from that bucket and run the bulk operation query.
In cURL it is working fine but then send the post request using python
it is giving me error
`InvalidArgument`Invalid argument.Cannot create buckets using a POST.

Python code

```
url = "https://url_to_bucket/"
payload={
    'Content-Type': 'text/jsonl',
    'success_action_status': '201',
    'acl': 'private',
    'key': 'upload_path_on_the_bucket',
    'x-goog-date': '20230404T073135Z',
    'x-goog-credential': 'merchant_credentials',
    'x-goog-algorithm': 'GOOG4-RSA-SHA256',
    'x-goog-signature': 'signature_token',
    'policy': 'policy_token',
    'file': 'file_contant'
}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

cURL Code

```
curl --location 'https://url_to_bucket/' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'Content-Type="text/jsonl"' \
--form 'success_action_status="201"' \
--form 'acl="private"' \
--form 'key="upload_path_on_the_bucket"' \
--form 'x-goog-date="20230404T073135Z"' \
--form 'x-goog-credential="merchant_credentials"' \
--form 'x-goog-algorithm="GOOG4-RSA-SHA256"' \
--form 'x-goog-signature="signature_token"' \
--form 'policy="policy_token"' \
--form 'file="file_contant"'
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Tried documentation of shopify and python to make a multipart/form-data request
but nothing worked for me

Comment: Have you tried pasting your cURL command into https://curlconverter.com/ to get some Python code?